# Lightweight library for cross-browser event support

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, dom-events, javascript-framework

Cross-browser handling is quite a hassle sometimes.

In this case I need to capture quite a number of events, but cannot afford to use a multi purpose library that exceeds **10ish Kb**. (e.g. jQuery, Prototype, Dojo, YUI, ...)

The script is meant as a basic tracking tool for various sites I'm maintaining.

**Every browser seems to handle events [slightly and sometimes completely differently](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)!**

[image]

---

**I would be really happy if someone could point me out to a Javascript library meant for cross-browser event handling.**

This would make my day! =)

Comment: speaking of size... do you need to include a 500K screen shot?

Comment: @scunliffe: haha... no way! I've obviously used the wrong tools to get that screenshot done... thanks for fixing it.

Comment: no worries at all, I was just on a slow wireless connection this morning and it rendered sooo slow! ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dean Edwards' :
http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event2/

Or the one from John Resig:
http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/

Comment: Pretty good links. The first one is simple and awesome. It is less than a KB. +1

Comment: @l.devries Thanks so much! I'll check these out! John Resig always has cool stuff on his blog! =)

Comment: Hey @devries, I'm not sure if this fixes the cross-browser incompatibility of focus and blur for example?

Comment: @RadiantHex what do you use for the server side? any good oss lib? Thx

Comment: @RadiantHex is there a better js lib now after these years? Thx

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how much event handling you need to do or if you're looking to add custom events, but here's another option if you're feeling curious. It uses Dean Edwards and adds on some bells and whistles to come in around 5K minified.

https://github.com/fat/bean

Comment: any oss lib recommendation for the server side? Only node.js or something at tomcat/java land?

Comment: is there a better js lib now after these years? Thx