# Browser plugin/extension to track search string

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I need to develop some sort of browser plugin/extension to track search string on some search engine web site, ex: google.com, bing.com. 
From the research, for chrome extension,  I saw somebody suggest content js is the way to go. Is it true? Is there a cross-browser approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content.JS or any other JS library you like for developing an extension but with only JS library you cannot develop an extension.

There is a specific way for each browser. It contains at least 4 files.

(1) Manifest file (2) HTML file (3) JS file (4) CSS file

You also need to refer browsers object model.

You can refer links below may help you to get more information.

(1) [Creating a Microsoft Edge extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/creating-an-extension)

(2) [Getting Started Tutorial to create an extension for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

(3) [Your first extension for FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)

To support cross browser functionality, You can try to port your chrome extension to Firefox or MS Edge. To get more information on porting an extension, you can refer links below.

(1) [Porting an extension from Chrome to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/porting-chrome-extensions)

(2) [Porting a Google Chrome extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Porting_a_Google_Chrome_extension)

Note:- You also need to refer policy of each browser to access browsing data of users. It can be possible that all browser has some difference in their policies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder if there is existing open source library which provides building block for cross-browser cross-mobile-pc functionality.

Comment: This question is informational. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317266/lightweight-library-for-cross-browser-event-support-javascript

Comment: Let me clear that extensions will not work on mobile devices because mobile browsers like chrome and edge does not supports extensions. Whether you use any cross browser JS library or not, you have to port it to use it in other browser. Porting converts the whole package and make it compatible for other browser.